# Generic type of class

Tags: java, android, generics

Is there a way to get the generic type of the following class at runtime (I will call `doSomething()` at runtime):

```
class MyClass<D> extends BaseClass<List<D>> {

    public Class<D> getGenericClass(){
        Type [] ta = ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments();
        Class ty = (Class) ta[0];   // is java.util.List<D> and throws a cast exception

       // TODO I want to know what kind of class "D" is
    }

}

class BaseClass<T>
   T data;
}
```

I would like to use the `MyClass` as follows:

```
MyClass<Foo> instance = new MyClass<Foo>();
Class<Foo> foo = instance.getGenericClass();
```

The lines of code from above are just to show you the (simplified) scenario I'm facing. If I would instantiate it by hand, then I would already know that I'm using `Foo` as generic parameter, but thats not the case.

FYI I'm trying to deal with Android `Parcelable` and to get the correct class loader for `readParcelable()` by using generics. Concrete: `MyClass implements Parcelable`. While reading the `Parcel` I have to specify a classloader like this `data = parcel.readArrayList(Foo.class.getClassLoader)` and I want to determine that dynamically by using reflections like `data = parcel.readArrayList(getGenericClass().getClassLoader())`

Is there a way to get that kind of information?

Typically you would just use:

```
Class type = (Class) (getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
```

but that returns `java.util.List<D>`, but I'm interested in what `<D>` is. Is there a way to dive into that generic type as well?

Comment: thanks, but I the with `getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments();` I get `java.util.List<D>` instead of `java.util.List<Foo>`. So is, there a way to get evaluate `<D>`?

Comment: Do you actually have multiple `ClassLoader`s in your application? I haven't seen a case where the type of the `Class` used to retrieve the `ClassLoader` mattered with `Parcelable`. Can you explain your situation a bit more?

Comment: Good Point, makes it any difference if `MyClass` is part of an `.aar` packed library?

Comment: No, you cannot find `D` at runtime. This is due to type erasure. Much like the matrix, "there is no D".

Comment: Thanks, I feared that. However, I thing @TomG is right at this point and it doesn't make any difference which class loader I use on android. But I'm not sure if MultiDex (65K problem) will need another class loader.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like (class from java.lang.reflect):

```
ParameterizedType pt = (ParameterizedType)MyClass.class.getGenericSuperclass();
Type[] t = pt.getActualTypeArguments();
```

`t` will contain each generic type of your class.

EDIT: if it's a list, you can reach the list type using something like:

```
ParameterizedType listType = (ParameterizedType) listField.getGenericType();
Class<?> listClass = (Class<?>) listType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

Comment: That works if you have a variable or a method signature with an actual type defined (i.e. `List<String>`). It can also work in the case of class hierarchy where a super class or interface defines a generic and the actual implementation provides a specific value for that generic (as opposed to still being generic to consumers). This use does not appear to fall into any of those categories.